# Using IF ........ End If in SSRS

Tags: report, reporting-services

I have a filed displayed on my report. But I want to make it visible or invisible, depending on user's choice. My form, that initiates the report, contains a check box, the value of the check box is stored in variable, say vrIfChecked.
I want to make the field hidden if the value in the variable is false
can I use something like

Collapse
if vrIfChecked="Checked" then
txtHeader.visible=true
else
txtHeader.visible=false
end if
If yes, where to write code and how to call it. Please give me complete steps for this.

Thanks a lot.
With best regards,
Furqan

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the text box you want to hide, click on “Text Box Properties” from the context menu. Go to the Visibility tab and select “Show or hide based on an expression”. Click on the fx next to the express and type

```
=iif(Parameters!YourPram="Checked",True,False)
```

That should work but I’m not a computer with that installed to check

Comment: I have defined a Boolean report parameter and used as you mentioned but how to connect that with my checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

A report isn't actually an html page where you can fully customize functionality within the report; where you can have a user check and uncheck something that is in the actual report body.  It either is or isn't.

The only way to have the user select anything the report with be based on is by using the parameters - say, includeCompanyLogo.  In the end, for printing, you can have an image where you want the the check box, and then use an expression for the image name, where the images of a checked box and unchecked box are embedded, say =iif(Parameters!includeCompanyLogo.value = true, "checkedImg", "uncheckedImg").  Then, for the logo, put it on your page as an image or rectangle fill or whatever, and just use that boolean parameter as your visibility value.